# level and coins increases as the button is pressed

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter

We just started Tkinter and as our professor in programming asked us if we could try to make a game using Tkinter as our final project in 1st year college, specifically 4 pics 1 word, I need assistance as to how can I increase the level to +1 and the coins to +10 whenever the next button is pressed? any insights are very much appreciated. The code and sample output is given below for reference [image]

```
from distutils.cmd import Command
from tkinter import *
from turtle import heading, width
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("4 pics 1 word")
root.geometry("500x650")
root.maxsize(500,650)
root.iconbitmap ("4picslogo.ico")

#Variable
levelno = 1
coins = 100
counter = 0
picNum = 0

#def
def nextlevel():
    global levelno
    levelno = levelno + 1
    if levelno==50:
        levelno=1
    global coins
    coins = coins + 10
        
def changeImage():
    global picNum
    picNum+=1
    if picNum==50:
        picNum=0
    pics.config(file=picfiles[picNum]+".png")
    nextPic.config(text="PASS "+str(picNum+1))

#Frames
frame_1 = Frame(root, width=500, height=150)
frame_1.pack (side=TOP)

frame_2 = Frame(root,width=500, height=300)
frame_2.pack ()

frame_3 = Frame(root, width=500, height=200)
frame_3.pack ()

#FrameOne (Level and coins bar)
Blue_bar = Label (frame_1, width=71,height=5,bg="#4472c4")
Blue_bar.grid()

levelcounter = Label (frame_1, text="Level: "+str(levelno), font=("Helvetica",25,"bold"),fg="white",bg="#4472c4")
levelcounter.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)

coinimg = PhotoImage(file="coins.png")
coins_pic = Canvas(frame_1, width=55, height=55, bg="#4472c4")
coins_pic.create_image(30,30, image=coinimg)
coins_pic.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=(320,0))

coin_counter = Label (frame_1, text=""+str(coins), font=("Helvetica",25,"bold"),fg="white",bg="#4472c4")
coin_counter.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=E,padx=(0,1))


#FrameTwo (Pictures to guess)
################################################################################################################################
f = open("picList.txt","r")
x = f.readlines()

picfiles = list()
for p in x:
    fn = p.strip().split(';')
    picfiles.append(fn[1])

pics = PhotoImage(file=picfiles[0]+".png")
pic_viewer = Label(frame_2,image=pics)
pic_viewer.grid(row=0,column=0,pady=(40,0))
################################################################################################################################

#FrameThree (Buttons)
button_picture_pass = PhotoImage(file='pass.png')
nextPic = Button(frame_3,image=button_picture_pass,text=""+str(levelno+1),command=lambda:[changeImage(), nextlevel()])
nextPic.grid(padx=(400,0),pady=(135,0))

quitbutton = Button(root,text="Save and Quit", command = root.quit)
quitbutton.pack(anchor=E,padx=(0,22))


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating `levelno` and `coins` will not update `levelcounter` and `coin_counter` automatically.  You need to update them inside `nextlevel()`:

```py
def nextlevel():
    global levelno, coins
    levelno += 1
    if levelno == 50:
        levelno = 1
    coins += 10
    # update counter labels
    levelcounter['text'] = f'Level: {levelno}'
    coin_counter['text'] = coins
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this code but do have some experience in writing code in general.

it seems the thing you want is already in this function

```
def nextlevel():
global levelno
levelno = levelno + 1
if levelno==50:
    levelno=1
global coins
coins = coins + 10
```

and here you define the Next button:

```
button_picture_pass = PhotoImage(file='pass.png')
```

and here you trigger the function to increase the level and money when pressed:

```
nextPic = Button(frame_3,image=button_picture_pass,text=""+str(levelno+1),command=lambda:[changeImage(), nextlevel()])
```

so I'm not sure what the question is :D